# What additional tools do i need with docker to send emails via an smtp server

Tags: exception, docker, smtp, mailkit

I am writing a .net core 1.1 console application. The goal is to host this as a scheduled job running inside a docker container.

The console app will use an smtp server and will send emails. Simple as that.

However, I am not successful while running the application inside a docker container. My assumption was that if we expose the smtp port out of the docker container, it should be all that is needed for the smtp server to work.

`docker run -it -p 25:25 --rm courierreports:demo`

The code is throwing exception while trying to connect to the smtp server. Do i need any additional tools to make my application work?

My machine is running windows 7 and i am using oracle virtual box for docker. The smtp server (`org.smtp.com`) is provided by my company I am using port `25`

The error i get:

```
fail: StartupLogs[0]
      An error occurred.
fail: StartupLogs[0]
      Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection timed out.
fail: StartupLogs[0]
         at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
         at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpStream.ReadAhead(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpStream.ReadResponse(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.Connect(String host, Int32 port, SecureSocketOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at MailKit.MailService.Connect(String host, Int32 port, Boolean useSsl, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Org.Dept.MailkitAdapter.MailkitSendMail.SendMail(MailMessage mailMsg) in C:\Workspace\POC\DotnetCore\Azure\Practice\EmailService\Org.Dept
.MailkitAdapter\MailkitSendMail.cs:line 31
         at Org.Legal.CourierReports.Logic.EmailProcessor.SendEmail(List`1 model) in C:\Workspace\POC\DotnetCore\Azure\Practice\EmailService\Org.Lega
l.CourierReports.Logic\EmailProcessor.cs:line 121
         at Org.Legal.CourierReports.Logic.EmailProcessor.TestSend() in C:\Workspace\POC\DotnetCore\Azure\Practice\EmailService\Org.Legal.CourierRepo
rts.Logic\EmailProcessor.cs:line 92
         at Org.Legal.CourierReports.Console.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Workspace\POC\DotnetCore\Azure\Practice\EmailService\Org.Legal.Courier
Reports.Console\Program.cs:line 42
```

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1-runtime
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Org.Legal.CourierReports.Console.dll"]
```

Here are the commands I used to build & run the docker container

```
docker build --no-cache -t courierreports:demo .
docker run -it -p 25:25 --rm courierreports:demo
```

Here is the code. it breaks at the line indicated with `=>`

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;

=>  client.Connect(mailMsg.MailOptions.SmtpHost, mailMsg.MailOptions.SmtpPortNoAuth, false);

    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

    client.Send(mimeMsg);

    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

Comment: Did you try connecting to it from your own machine outside of Docker?

Comment: yes it was tried on my local machine outside docker and also deployed it as an azure web job. Both cases the application works and i am able to receive emails.

Comment: Looks like your docker is blocked by a firewall.